# What does "mertilize" mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I have been unable to find a definition, or a source for the word *mertilize*. I've seen it used on TV, in articles, and even in comic strips.

Comment: Do you have any examples? If so, please edit, rather than commenting.

Comment: Mertilize:
to annihilate.
I gotta get the car back by 8, or Dad's gonna mertilize me! 

Crew, set your phazers to maximum mertilize. From Urban Dict.

Comment: @Josh61 - can that be right? I thought that was *murdalize*. That is a very old word (like, scores of years). I remember that in *Loony Toons* cartoons.

Comment: @medica Yes, it’s *murdalize*.  People don’t know how to spell things these days. :)  It’s a take on *murder > murderize* with a swap of R and L.

Comment: @medica, I just spend a perfectly good lunch break trying to find one of those instances that I'm sure I heard too - with no luck!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming it's the same word I've heard and seen many times in cartoons and old movies, the word is "murderlize" and as it's defined in the [Dictionary of American Slang](http://amslang.enacademic.com/6518/Murderlize).

It is a variation on a threat to cause bodily harm to someone, but said in a funny way..."I'll *murderlize* you!"

Comment: And don't forget the rare form "myrtleize," used only when a Myrtle is doing the murderlizing!

Comment: All seriousness aside, my "myrtleize" is obviously a joke, but I grew up with the Three Stooges and remember hearing them use "murderlize" even before hearing Bugs use it (which he did).  Anyway, here's a link to a book, "Hollywood and Crime" (about 30 or so books from the top), published in 2007, containing the short story "Murderlized" about a 1937 murderlization!   http://www.threestooges.net/bibliography

Answer (score 4):

It is a slang term meaning "to destroy or annihilate". Usually, this destruction is done in a fantastical way with a heavy leaning on science-fiction elements.

It is not a very common term and the earliest usage I could find was [Calvin and Hobbes from January 2009](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/2009/01/02):

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that variation on the spelling may be from the Calvin and Hobbes era but the word itself dates back to early movies and cartoons.

Comment: Good to know Kristina.  Can you give an example of an earlier usage.  I couldn't find one.

Comment: I tried, really I did!  Apparently it's not in print form (per ngram) and I tried searching YouTube but I got no hits on any variation of the word.  I only know that I heard it on TV in the 60's and that it was commonly used amongst us kids back then.  I can actually *hear* Bugs Bunny saying it - with a New Jersey ('joisey') accent! lol!

Comment: The three stooges used this term often.  "Oh, a wiseguy huh?  I'll murderize ya!".  So it was in use in the 30's to 40's

Comment: Watterson's Calvin & Hobbes ended in 1995, however, which would place this source at least that early. It doesn't change the other references, of course, but it's worth noting.

Comment: Yeah, that totally predates my memory, but I totally appreciate you trying to find a reference. :)  I wonder when it went from murderlize to mertilize and how different the pronunciations are (I have only seen it in print form).  I totally didn't get the murder root from mertilize, but it makes total sense from the definition.

Comment: January 2009 is definitely not the correct date of the comic.  I can make out the date 11-20 in the third panel but not the copyright year in the fourth.  However, [here](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1985/12/08) is another strip with a mertilizer which is dated December 8, 1985 - the earliest mention of the term in *Calvin and Hobbes* (the strip only started a few weeks prior, and I checked all the previous strips).

Comment: It should be noted that Calvin/Watterson loved to invent new words like "mertilizer beam".  There's probably an invented word in about every 10th strip, and almost certainly one in every Spaceman Spiff strip.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is from Duck Dodgers or Marvin the Martian, a couple decades earlier than Calvin and Hobbes.  The word might even have been used by Laurel and Hardy, a few decades earlier.

Comment: The last digit of the copyright year looks like a 7, which would make the whole year 1987, so that strip is from [November 20, 1987](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1987/11/20).

Comment: @Jen:  *mertilize* and *murderlize* sound very similar in American English. The /t/, /d/ distinction disappears because both of these are converted into flaps, and the difference between /əl/ and /ərl/ in an unaccented syllable is fairly small.

Answer (score 4):

Murdelize is the combination of "murder" and "pulverize." It was a commonly used piece of dialogue in the original "Three Stooges" TV series used as a threat or in response to some perceived wrong.
The Stooges are the earliest record of the word I could find.

Comment: It was in early Warner Bros. cartoons as well, though the stooges may have had it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you may be thinking of is "marmalise".

EDIT: In spite of a downvote, I'll press on.

"Marmalize", from Wiktionary: "To thrash", "To defeat decisively". Alternative spelling "Marmalise".

In the UK we never really had the Three Stooges so can't comment, but as someone who is exposed to Looney Tunes cartoons virtually every day, this is unquestionably the word that Bugs Bunny uses, "Why I'll marmalize ya!". Also, many of the other characters use it on the same context.

Comment: I never heard of that Lefty.  It sounds a little like marmalade! :-) (FYI - I'm not the downvoter!)

Comment: Maybe if you'd spelled it with a 'z' in your first line more people would have been able to recognize it as a legitimate answer! (I got you back to even)

Comment: @Papa Thanks, you're probably right but I'm British and tend to leave the "z" spellings to Americans (as a rule).